# why we use {get; set;} syntax in wrapper class or in controller class

Tags: apex, getter, setter

```
public class Wrapper
{

   public String fname{get; set;} //why we use get; set; syntax here
   public String lname{get; set;}
   public String uname{get; set;}
}
```

also here

```
public class Controller{
    public List<Wrapper> WrapperList {get;set;}
    public string sourceURL {get; set;}
}
```

how these get; set; methods work.

Comment: If any of the below answers [addressed your problem](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers), please consider [accepting one](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234) by clicking on the check mark/tick to the left of the answer, turning it green. This marks the question as resolved to your satisfaction, and awards [reputation](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) both to you and the person who answered. If you have >= 15 reputation points, you may also upvote the answer if you wish. There is no obligation to do either.

Answer (score 13):

`{get; set;}` can appear in any apex class, next to any class variable (thus making it a 'property').

The `<access identifier> <type> <variable name> {get; set;}` pattern is simply a shortcut. Using that syntax tells Salesforce to automatically generate the getter and setter methods for that class variable.

Of course, you don't *need* to use that syntax, but then again, we also don't *need* to use automobiles to travel long distances (walking will do the job just fine, albeit more slowly).

If you don't feel like using this:

```
public class MyClass{
    public String myVariable {get; set;}
}
```

You can always do it the long way

```
public class MyClass{
    public String myVariable;

    public void setMyVariable(String input){
        myVariable = input;
    }

    public String getMyVariable(){
        return myVariable;
    }
}
```

With having public class variables though, you don't really need to specify setters and getters. You can just get/set the value directly.

However, for reasons that are beyond the scope of this answer (and this site), directly accessing class variables is poor practice in object-oriented programming (Apex being an object-oriented programming language).

Comment: Loved this comment "Of course, you don't need to use that syntax, but then again, we also don't need to use automobiles to travel long distances (walking will do the job just fine, albeit more slowly)"

Comment: "directly accessing class properties is poor practice" - do you really mean properties (pairs of accessor methods), or do you mean class *variables*?

Comment: @TannerSwett After doing some due diligence it appears that you're right in pointing out my misuse of the 'property' term. Will fix.

Comment: There is a concrete difference, which is that defining a variable with only `{get}` or `{set}` will disable the other accessor, so the variable cannot be modified/read outside the accessor (useful for e.g. lazy load variables).  Alternatively, this could be considered equivalent to only defining a `getMyVariable` or `setMyVariable` method without actually having a `myVariable` class variable.

Answer (score 5):

Take a look at the [`Visualforce Developer Guide`](https://resources.docs.salesforce.com/sfdc/pdf/salesforce_pages_developers_guide.pdf) (page 120):

> ## Defining Getter Methods
>
> One of the primary tasks for a Visualforce controller class is to give developers a way of displaying database and other computed values
>   in page markup. Methods that enable this type of functionality are called getter methods, and are typically named `get`***`Identifier`***,
>   where `Identifier` is the name for the records or primitive values returned by the method.
>
> For example, the following controller has a getter method for returning the name of the controller as a string:
>
> ```
> public class MyController {
>     public String getName() {
>         return 'MyController';
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> To display the results of a getter method in a page, use the name of the getter method without the `get` prefix in an expression. For
>   example, to display the result of the getName method in page markup, use `{!name}`:
>
> ```
> <apex:page controller="MyController">
>     <apex:pageBlock title="Hello {!$User.FirstName}!">
>         This is your new page for the {!name} controller.
>     </apex:pageBlock>
> </apex:page>
> ```

---

It's also worth reading [this blog post from '08](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2008/06/property-access.html):

> #### Visualforce interactions
>
> I found an interesting Visualforce interaction. In a Visualforce page you can have something like
>
> ```
> <apex:outputLink rendered="{!mustrender}" value="coo" >Click Me!</apex:outputLink>
> ```
>
> This makes an implicit call to the method `getMustRender()`. In fact, the editor suggests creating such a method if it doesn’t exist in the controller. Interestingly, you can also define a property in the controller instead, ie.:
>
> ```
>  public Boolean mustrender {get;set;}
> ```
>
> Now the Visualforce page will work just fine, even though there is no `getMustRender()` method. Obviously it’s enough for the property to exist.

Answer (score 4):

If you are capturing the data from UI or from external interfaces and want to store the those attibute values inside a class, you have to define them as attributes.

`getter` - returning value of the attribute

`setter` - assigning value to that attribute

```
InfoWrap obj = new InfoWrap();
obj.fname = 'Test'; //setter will fire
```

In visualforce, if you use this code, then `getter` will fire.

```
<apex:outputText value="{!obj.fname}"/>
```

Let's say you are building instance of wrapper class like this:

```
public List<Wrapper> getWrapperList()
{
    List<Wrapper> lstWrapper = new List<Wrapper>();
    InfoWrap obj = new InfoWrap();
    obj.fname = 'Test';
    lstWrapper.add(obj);

    InfoWrap obj2 = new InfoWrap();
    obj2.fname = 'Test2';
    lstWrapper.add(obj2);
    return lstWrapper;
}
```

And use that list like this way, then `getter` will fire:

```
<apex:repeat value="{!WrapperList}" var="w">
   <apex:outputText value="{!w.fname}" /> <br/>
</apex:repeat>
```

And, if you are changing the value of the `outputText` then setter will fire.

Comment: and what does these two lines mean   public List<Wrapper> WrapperList {get;set;}
    public string sourceURL {get; set;} why get set is used here.in my case i am reading the data from external url in json format.could you please explain how it works.

Comment: if you are reading the data, use getter, and if you are capturing the data from UI and assigning the data to save in database or pass it to external system then use setter

Answer (score 2):

**This is how Visualforce framework works.**

Since this a MVC architecture so, framework (View) requires a common medium to interact with Controller. So, for the properties framework expect two methods:-

1. *get*`Propertyname`: To get the value form the controller and use on the page
2. *set*`Propertyname`: To set the value into controller form the Visualforce page. It takes single argument which must be same as `Type` of property you have defined.

> Both (getter and setter) must be at least to `public` access level so,
>   Visualforce framework can access them.
>
> - Visualforce always expect `{get;set;}` for the property.
> - If you don not provide `{get;set;}` then it looks for methods named *get*`Propertyname`.
> - If nothing above exists and property is used on Visualforce page, exception will be thrown.

**Apex has provide you the shortcut way to generate these methods on its end just by appending `{get;set;}` to follow with framework.**

Comment: You can often access properties with a `private set`. Can you share the link you reference here?

Comment: You can't. You will get "Read only property 'Controller.proprtyName'` when you try to update it. That's the purpose of `set;` @AdrianLarson

Comment: Yes but often properties are just used for output and should not even be writable. And this syntax does work outside the context of Visualforce...

Comment: That's the use case thing. I often edit but you may not. There can be other use cases also. When I say access, it mean full access of supported operations. You may improve the text if you find it misleading. @AdrianLarson

Comment: I mean...it's factually incorrect top say you *need* a public setter to access properties on a page. A simple `outputField` will demonstrate.